# Unable to kill process, launchctl unload/remove failed

Tags: macos, terminal, kill, launchctl

I have a process running in the background from a trial I once had installed (Bitdefender Antivirus). I tried uninstalling it but there's some parts that I did not manage to get off my computer.

Here's what I tried so far:

Activity Monitor: I see the process there but neither "quit" nor "force quit" do anything. At every startup, the process has a different PID.

I ran "launchctl" in the terminal, first using the "list" command to look up the process and then tried "launchctl remove "com.bitdefender.antivirusformac" but without success. Putting "sudo" in front didn't change anything either.

I then tried to unload it by typing "launchctl unload "/Library/LaunchAgents/com.bitdefender.antivirusformac.plist" but that didn't do anything as well.

Aside from the ".plist" file, there are also two LaunchDaemons (located in /library/LaunchDaemons) called "com.bitdefender.AuthHelperTool.plist" and "com.bitdefender.upgrade.plist"

Does anyone know how I can get permanently rid of these processes/files?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you know the file locations of those processes and services you can surely do it.I have been in the same position as of yours and i have found a really awesome solution to it.Umm.. it's a third-party software but works like magic "**LockHunter**" download it. What it does is it takes the file location path and then unlocks any processes that are making it tough to remove or if this does not work it takes the file location path and deletes the processes as soon as the PC boots

Comment: Isn't that a Windows-Tool? I'm running macOS 10.12.5...

Comment: Oh! But you never told me that!.. Please edit it in your question..Well, There's another one for you luckily .. It works in mac OS .. I don't know much about it .. so just try working with it .. It is "** Lock -UnMatic **"